# Converting time into Hours, minutes, and seconds

Tags: c++

I was writing a c++ program that converts time into: hours, minutes, and seconds. 
 
What I need to do is to convert time into the form of: HH:MM:SS, anyways 
 here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long time, hour, min, sec;
    cout<<"Enter elapsed time: ";
    cin>>time;
    cout<<time;
    hour = time/3600;
    min = (time%3600) / 60;
    sec = (time%3600) % 60;
    cout<<"\nIn HH:MM:SS -> ";
    cout<<hour<<":"<<min<<":"<<sec;
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter time in example: 3600, it displays 1:0:0 unlike the form I'm looking forward, so I need it to be displayed as "01:00:00" in this form. What should I do?

Comment: @scohe001 That's not a duplicate. My question is different.

Comment: Your question seems to be asking for a way to ensure the number of digits for Hours/Min/Sec are the same by padding 0's. Can you explain why the other question is different from yours?

Comment: It's not a good idea to write your own times; instead you should use something like [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) if possible. I'm not sure exactly how to use that or this would be an answer, but a lot can go wrong if you try to do it yourself. See https://youtu.be/QCwpVtqcqNE for an example of when this can go wrong.

Comment: @scohe001 Why do I get downvotes, explain please?

Comment: I can't speak for everyone else, but I downvoted because you weren't able to distinguish your question from the one I posted. As such, it looks like you didn't put in the effort to research this problem before you posted (see http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ for more info). I'm always willing to change my vote if you can prove me wrong though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `<iomanip>` and use `std::setfill` and `std::setw` to define what character you want to use to fill and what is the width of the field to be printed.

```
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << hour << ":"; 
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << min << ":" 
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << sec;
```

Comment: @FrankS101 Can you explain why we made the value of setw(2)?

Comment: setw(n) sets the width parameter of the output stream exactly to n. If you provide something smaller to the output stream (like 1 or 0 in your example) it will be filled by default with spaces, but with setfill('0) is filled with 0s

Comment: it's still not working fine  for hour > 99.